# undefined method `group' for #<Poll:0x007f0a1c2610b0>[Chartkick]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I've create a mini poll game and I want to show the user's votes in pie chart. I used Chartkick to do that, my code here:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= content_tag(:label) do %>
        <% unless current_user.voted_for?(@poll) %>
            <%= radio_button_tag 'vote_option[id]', option.id %>
        <% end %>
        <%= option.title %>
    <% end %>
    <%= visualize_votes_for option %>
    <%= pie_chart @poll.group(:title).count('votes') %>
</div>
```

I expected to display `option.title` and `option.votes` correspondingly. Here is a `vote_option.rb` model:

```
class VoteOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :votes

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

And here is the error that I got:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `group' for #<Poll:0x007f0a1c2610b0>)
```

Any idea for this issue?

Comment: Maybe you meant `@poll.poll_options.group(:title).count('votes')`?

Comment: @DylanMarkow I had no `poll_options` method in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solved***
After hours searching, I recognized my error: we can't call .group on an instance of the model, and we have to call it on the model class so that why I got this error.